# Sidebar width could not adjust

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a sidebar for my html page. But i could not adjust the width of the sidebar. Also the menu icon when click should be closing/open the sidebar but it does not work.

Im a new learner , please help.

[My code at here!](http://jsfiddle.net/zpnhjcyd/1/)

```
#sidebar {
    background:#151719;
    height:1000px;
    width:20%; <!--- Cannot adjust width --->
    position:absolute;
    left:-248px; <!--- this will let the sidebar disapper --->
    transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: You have a number of errors in your CSS. The jsfiddle color coding points out most of them; make sure to correct those. Also, if you're trying to move the #sidebar when the checkbox is checked, why doesn't the CSS target the sidebar when it is?

Comment: could u help to correct those errors ? im not sure how to correct them

Comment: OK, I just posted an answer.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. Yes it is possible to do such a thing in pure CSS when an `input` is checked. But you need to put it is in the right place. For example as a parent of the element you want to be selected or a sibling; then you will be able to use `~` or `+` operator for selection. I did the same in `uicuxd.com` an it works properly. Source of it is available on `github.com/uicuxd/website` with comment. See the `div#navigation` code and where is `input#navigation-control`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but comment separators should be `/*`..`*/`, not `<!---`..`--->`. CSS is not HTML. Those comments prevent the CSS from being parsed correctly.

Then there is a `#sidebar {width: 100%;` halfway down, which overrides the `width:248%;` on the top.

And finally, the selector for moving the sidebar on selecting the checkbox should be `#menuToggle:checked ~ #sidebar`. Yours did nothing.

If you correct those errors, the page works flawlessly.

```css
*{padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-family:sans-serif;}
#sidebar{
 background:#151719;
 height:1000px;
 width:248px; /* Cannot adjust width */
 position:absolute;
 left:-248px; /* this will let the sidebar disapper */
 transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
 -o-transition:all .3 ease-in-out;
 }
#sidebar .menu li{
 list-style-type:none;}
#sidebar .menu a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:rgba(230,230,230,0.9);
 display:block;
 padding:15px 0;
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.45);}
#header{
 width:100%;
 height:5%;
 margin:auto;
 border-bottom:1px solid #EEE;}
#header .brand{
 float:left;
 line-height:50px;
 color:#151719;
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-left:20px;}
#sidebar{
 /* width:100%; */ /* removed because this would override the 248px above */
 text-align:center;}
#sidebar .menu li:last-child a{border-bottom:none;}
#sidebar a:hover{
 background:grey;
 color:black;}
.menu-icon{
 margin:2.5px 5px 0px 0px;
 padding:10px 15px;
 border-radius:5px;
 background:#151719;
 color:rgba(230,230,230,0.9);
 cursor:pointer;
 float:right;}
#menuToggle:checked ~ #sidebar {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;} /* Not sure is it correct or not, by clicking the checkbox, the sidebar should be displayed nicely, back to original */
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle" style="display:none;">
<label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</label>

<div id="header">
 <div class="brand">Cinema</div>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
 <ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Help Center</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Summary</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Customer Interface</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Good job saying the obvious, but nobody asked about CSS comments. Your solution is risky since it relies on HTML structure that is very likely to break at some point. Thank you for bringing it up, I appended it to my answer.

Comment: @fingeron If you check the css, you will see that the OP's `width:20%; <!--- Cannot adjust width --->
    position:absolute;` does not work, while my `width:20%; /* Cannot adjust width */
    position:absolute;` does. This is caused, as I said in my answer, by the fact that `<!---` prevents the CSS from being parsed correctly. I.E. the `position` gets ignored.

Comment: You are right, but this is not why his solution wasn't working and you know it. He added those comments for us.

Comment: @fingeron Have you also read the rest of my answer? There were more things wrong with the CSS and they all needed to be corrected before it worked.

Comment: And I'm not sure why you say a solution is risky because it depends on the order of the HTML elements. Of course it does, but that's what the checkbox trick is all about. The OP's HTML was tailored to make it work. I could just as well say your solution is risky because it relies on the ids in the HTML; that would be equally silly.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the override, yet again, the question was about the interaction between a checkbox and a div. I don't know about you, but my goal is to make people learn and understand, and not supply a copy paste solution. Therefore, fixing the interaction between the two, be it JS or CSS, would lead the OP to notice other, unrelated errors.

In today's world wide web, a lot of the thinking is done in components. Simply put, it is less likely for two `#sidebar` elements to exist than for the `#menuToggle` to be placed *after* the said `#sidebar`.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for your help. My sidemenu should be on the right side so I declare `left:-248px` but it shows on the left side

Comment: @hatched If you want it on the right side, you should use `right:-248px;` (and `right:0;` when the checkbox is clicked). A problem with that though is once it has been made visible, you can't click the checkbox again to hide it again, since the sidebar will be on top of it. Unless you move the checkbox to the left.

Answer (score 0):

you can set width like this :

```
width: 20vw;
left: 0; // left: -20vw;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your styles are applied to the `#menuToggle` item. Therefore **the sidebar never hears about this change**.

```
#menuToggle:checked {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

Also because both elements do not have HTML relations, a CSS workaround might be risky. It's important to mention the selector `#menuItem ~ #sidebar` which will select `#sidebar`s that precede `#menuItem`.

```
#menuToggle:checked ~ #sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

Although it is definitely more prone to break in the future when the website has more content.

I suggest you have an event listener on the checkbox to toggle a class on the sidebar element. This can be done like so:

```
document.getElementById('menuItem').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
     let sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
     this.checked ?
          sidebar.classList.add('active') :
          sidebat.classList.remove('active');
});
```